# Redux Form Field Level Validation does not work in Edge

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-edge, redux-form

I am using the example code in this path https://redux-form.com/6.6.3/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/ to validate number input

```
const number = value => value && isNaN(Number(value)) ? 'Must be a number' : undefined
```

It won't stop me from typing non-numeric characters in the Microsoft Edge. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `type="number"` converts the input to a number input field. On mobile you would get the keyboard with only numbers on it. So it' more a browser thing. The validation will just prevent submitting and showing error messages when entering wrong values.

If you want to do this on your on use the `onKeyPress` event:

```
const NumberInput = ()=>{

  const onKeyPress = (e) => {
    if(e.which<48 || e.which>57) {
      e.preventDefault()
    }
  }

  return (
    <input onKeyPress={onKeyPress} />
  )
}
```

small example: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-lichterman-7eel4

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know it is a browser related issue. The requirement I got is to stop user from typing non-numeric. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: I've edited my answer with a small example to show the principle. Of course you've to advance it with onChange-handler etc.